# Are there any unofficial distributions of ros?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know the official distributions like Groovy or Hydro, but are there any other unofficial distributions?
We all know that Linux have many distributions. So I guess unofficial distributions may be exist.
Looking forward to the answers.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197731/are-there-any-unofficial-distributions-of-ros?/) by [sukha](https://answers.ros.org/users/19709/sukha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Groovy or Hydro aren't different distributions, but distribution releases. They are more like Ubuntu Lucid, Ubuntu Precise, etc.

A ROS distribution basically collects matching stacks together: http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions#What_is_a_Distribution.3F
I'm not sure if there is an overview on that. I would consider something like the turtlebot image a distribution.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sukha](https://answers.ros.org/users/19709/sukha/) on 2014-11-20**:
OK, I kinds of understand the difference between distribution and distribution release. Thank you.
As you see, what I really want to know is the unofficial distribution to ROS, like red hat to Linux.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-11-24**:
According to the link above a distribution is a collection of stacks/packages. Besides robot-specific ones I'm not aware of many ROS distros, mainly because packages usually are not mutually exclusive. The only thing you'd change would be drivers/algorithms. AFAIK there is only one core ROS implemen

**Comment by [sukha](https://answers.ros.org/users/19709/sukha/) on 2014-11-24**:
Thank you, that's really help me out.